# Why are there two modules defined in the authentication module in the NgRx example app?

Tags: angular, ngrx

The NgRx library for Angular provides an example application in its source code repository that illustrates the use of NgRx. In this application there is a module for authentication. In the [authentication module file](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/2a22211d5948d033df108cd71223ba7a69536ee8/example-app/app/auth/auth.module.ts) two modules are defined, one called `AuthModule` and the other called `RootAuthModule`.

I have a few questions about this:

1. Why are there two modules in the authentication feature module? Why not just one?
2. What purpose does each serve?
3. When creating a new feature module in Angular using NgRx, when would one choose the two module design over the one module design?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose its organized this way to separate whats needed on app startup (`forRoot`) and what can be reimported throughout the application.

The first module (`AuthModule`) is the module you would actually import and call `forRoot` when it's consumed by the `app.module`. The second module `RootAuthModule` defines all the imports that should only occur **once** in the application.

It really comes down to how you organize things, if there wasn't components that needed to be exported the developer would probably just have had one module defined. Since there are services **and** components that need wired up, they chose to group all the root based stuff in one, and all the non-root based stuff in another.

Comment: The whole pattern is getting more and more convoluted by the day.

Comment: I couldnt agree more.  It would be nice if Angular provided a ngModuleRoot decorator that would automatically throw when you tried to import outside app startup.  I feel like this is something that will just improve over time.

Comment: Part of the problem is you cannot see what an `ngModule` provides/declares/exports without looking at the source code and even if you have it handy, you have to navigate many levels. They should use a bunch of overloaded function declarations that use TypeScript's tuple types to infer the elementwise types of these things up to say 20.

Comment: @AluanHaddad what do you mean? Could you provide a gist?

Comment: yeah, I'll write one

Comment: Here is a gist with an example. Copy and paste into your IDE, notice all of the information, how it is preserved. https://gist.github.com/aluanhaddad/11c8ad3b37809bfdd097835a1c1d5d88